# Problem after installing DRCSim

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've had ROS and Gazebo working fine (Hydro and Gazebo 1.9 on Ubuntu 12.04). Today I installed DRCsim, and now when I try ROSlaunching (or ROSrun) a gazebo_ros package I get the following error:

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 10651, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver worlds/willowgarage.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/nbanyk/.ros/log/ebba1d2e-1c34-11e4-9f03-00216a935c82/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/nbanyk/.ros/log/ebba1d2e-1c34-11e4-9f03-00216a935c82/gazebo-2*.log

[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 10656, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/nbanyk/.ros/log/ebba1d2e-1c34-11e4-9f03-00216a935c82/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/nbanyk/.ros/log/ebba1d2e-1c34-11e4-9f03-00216a935c82/gazebo_gui-3*.log

Currently in my .bashrc file I have the following (bottom two lines were commented because I was troubleshooting to see if that would help):
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=/home/user/catkin_ws/src/
export EDITOR='nano -w'
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-1.9:/usr/share/gazebo_models:~/catkin_ws/src
source /usr/share/drcsim/setup.sh
source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh

The interesting thing is that roslaunching the drcsim_gazebo package does work, for example:
roslaunch drcsim_gazebo atlas_drc_vehicle_fire_hose.launch

I saw other related questions on this forum and have tried killing all gzserver's that are running.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6748/problem-after-installing-drcsim/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-08-05**:
also getting this error: gzserver: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEE
gzclient: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEE
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gazebo: 25: kill: invalid signal number or name: SIGINT

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-08-05**:
maybe this will get resolved here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1222/latest-debian-update-breaks-ros-hydro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It was a problem with ROS ABI, it should be fixed.

The reference for the problem is:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1222/latest-debian-update-breaks-ros-hydro

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-08-06**:
thanks, that fixed it!